# Search for all instances of 'IP len =' from Data packet capture file

Tags: ruby

I have a txt file that I've used to capture data packets over my network. I'm wondering if anyone would be able to tell me how I can use regular expressions to search for all instances of `'IP len ='` in the file, and extract them into another file perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little script will do the trick (amend as you like):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

File.open('infile.txt', 'r') do |infile|
    File.open('outfile.txt', 'w') do |outfile|
        while (line = infile.gets) do
            if line =~ /IP\s+len\s+=/ then
                outfile.puts line
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `line.match(...)` might be a more Ruby-like way of doing it. `=~` is inherited from Perl.

Comment: <Ether dst=00:1f:9f:3c:de:f2 src=00:26:bb:03:b2:44 |><IP len=64 id=0xf168 flags=2 chksum=0x87d9 src="192.168.1.67" dst="209.80.46.58" |><TCP sport=61582 seq=3125557437 dataofs=11 window=65535 chksum=0xbab8 |><Raw load="\002\004\005\264\001\003\003\001\001\001\b\n*\231\254P\000\000\000\000\004\002" |> 

That's an example of the packet that is stored in the output.txt file I have. 

I have about 300 packets like this saved in the file. 

Thanks for your reply, but I can't seem to get it to output anything to the outfile.txt.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
File.open("log.txt", 'r') do |f|
  File.open("ip_len_out.txt", 'w') do |out|
    f.lines.each do |line|
      out.puts $1 if line.match(/IP\s+len\s*=(\d+)/)
    end
  end
end
```

`ip_len_out.txt` now contains all the ip lengths, new line delimited.